# Get selected value from HTML.DropDownList back to controller (.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In a MVC application, I have a view showing tasks. The tasks should be filtered by employees to which they are assigned. Employees are shown in a dropdownlist.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeDropUsed", "Task", new { id = ?? }))
{
    @Html.DropDownList(
        "EmployeeDrop", new SelectList(Model.Employees, "Id", "EmployeeName"), "Select employee",
        new
        {
            onchange = @"
            var form = document.forms[0]; 
            form.submit();"
        })
}
```

I have a TaskController with an ActionResult, taking the data from the form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EmployeeDropUsed(int id)
{
    Employee e = er.GetById(id);
    return LoadControls(er.GetAll(), e.Tasks.ToList());
}
```

The ViewModel looks like this

```
public class TaskModel
{
    public TaskModel(List<Employee> employees, List<Task> tasks)
    {
        Employees = employees;
        Tasks = tasks;
    }

    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is I don´t know how to get the selected value from the drop back to the controller. I tried using DropDownListFor and an EmployeeId property in the model:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.EmployeeId, Model.Employees, "Select Employee")

public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

The result is that id is always 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `EmployeeDropUsed` action is looking for a parameter named `id` and the parameter you are sending it is `EmployeeId`.  Either change the parameter name on the `EmployeeDropUsed` action to `employeeId` or change the `EmployeeId` property on `TaskModel` to `id`.

If you change the `TaskModel` property this should work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, Model.Employees, "Select Employee")
```

If you change the `EmployeeDropUsed` parameter this should work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmployeeId, Model.Employees, "Select Employee")
```

Comment: Great! If I change all id to EmployeeId, it works. I still do not really get why, but thanks!

Comment: The default Model Binding in MVC takes form values, route values, and query string values and maps them to parameters in your actions. For that to work properly, the names all have to match. In this situation your view was creating a form value named EmployeeId. Model binding didn't find any parameter on the action named EmployeeId so it ignored it. Once you renamed the paramter to match the form value, it found it and set it for you. Here is a decent article on Model Binding:  http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Isn't that lambda expression incorrect though? Shouldn't it be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmployeeId ....
```

instead of

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.EmployeeId
```

Comment: Good catch, wasn't paying attention to that part when I was copy/pasting from question.